# Can I ask question about features of tools like Burp Suite?

Tags: discussion

I am testing a site using Burp Suite and stuck at a point. Is it okay to ask question regarding a features of tools like Burp Suite and other scanners ?

Answer (score 2):

Questions about security tools are generally on-topic, as listed in the [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The [burp-suite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burp-suite) tag in particular is quite active with generally well-received questions. You should have good chances to get a quick response for questions related to Burp features.

Personally though, I'm not a big fan of questions about (commercial) security products: Many of them could have been asked without naming and advertising the specific security tool. That is, a lot of Burp questions are in fact just generic questions about HTTP interception proxies. Further, the dedicated customer support forums are sometimes a better fit for questions about commercial tools than SE.

Comment: I have skimmed customer supports forum but the feature am looking for is not available in Burp. [Here is my question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155434/how-do-i-extract-data-from-response-in-burp-suite-intruder)

Comment: If you want a feature in burp, but it doesn't have it, that is a perfect time to contact Portswigger. If it is a useful feature request, then he may end up doing it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Okay I will do that.